# Add background/shade on app name

Tags: launcher, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

I would like to have a background appear around my app name, like in the image below. I have looked around quite a bit and have not been able to find anything to help me achieve this. Are there any settings/ways to have this feature? Or do I have to use 3rd-party app?

[image: SampleImage]

<sup>The screen showing the app name with dark background from [aHome Theme: openSUSE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.bbase.ahome.theme.opensuse)

(click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: The link provided in the question serves a clear solution. The background is a theme to be used as an add-on to aHome or aHome Lite. When clicked, it yielded a page not found, but a simple search would have led you to the right page for the launcher(s) in question to [download](http://www.mobogenie.com/download-ahome-lite-20847.html) and install, then allowing the theme in question.

Comment: That doesn't work - aHome does not come from the Google Play Store and it does not seem to be functioning properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve my intended result  by installing ADW Launcher from the Google Play Store.

Comment: Could you mention the link of this app?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dadw+l&pcampaignid=APPU_1_9l55VZElxMawBcKwg6gP

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different launcher, I know Nova Launcher can do this. You will have to setup all your apps, folders and widgets again though.

Comment: Could you mention the link for the said app?

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to how I can achieve this through Nova? I cannot find any settings/features within the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am also using Nova Launcher. Try the free version before you decide to buy the premium. You can personalize every aspect of your app icon, widget, shortcut etc. But i think you need to be accustomed with the interface.